# In vue.js when building for production, I get a 404 error on files inside the static folder, even when the URL is correct

Tags: webpack, vue.js, three.js

I'm trying to get my application ready for production and everything is working perfect in dev. However, when I run the build and upload it to the server, it only loads the HTML, Javascript, some CSS and some files. It gives me a 404 error on a few files inside the 'static' folder (not all), even when those paths are correct and it should find the files inside there.

I should mention I've tried adding a base to the vue-router, as well as changing the webpack assetsPublicPath to (/folder/) since the app is being served inside a folder in the server. I've also tried assetsSubDirectory with 'static', './static' to no avail.

I used the default WPA template from the vue-cli when setting up the project.

Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I realized only .obj files were giving me the error (3D model files). So I found this answer which finally solved the issue:
[Three.js Loading .OBJ error in Azure but not Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097580/three-js-loading-obj-error-in-azure-but-not-locally)

Answer (score 0):

Static copys the files to `/dist`. Yes It works with webpack dev server

Example: You have a png file in the static folder. 
The url is **`hostname/image.png`** insted of `hostname/static.png`